# Using Powershell to test-path on a network drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I can't get the Test-Path cmdlet to find a folder on a remote system's additional drive.

The following works for the system drive.

```
Test-Path -PATH '\\ServerName\C$\FolderName'
```

The next example always returns false.

```
Test-Path -PATH '\\ServerName\D$\FolderName'
```

I have verified the path and its spelling. Test-Path will find the path if I remote to the computer and run

```
Test-Path -PATH 'D:\FolderName'
```

I must be missing something. Will someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Can you navigate to the same UNC path via Windows Explorer? Is the `D` drive a logical disk attached to the remote system, or is it a drive letter that's mapped when you log in?

Answer (score 0):

You need specified the UNC path in this way.

```
$path = 'filesystem::\\servername\D$\FolderName'
If(Test-path -Path $path){
  Your code....
}
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/13/powertip-test-the-presence-of-a-remote-share-by-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the `d`-drive in this instance is not a logical disk on `ServerName` but a remote drive...

The `Get-PSDrive` CmdLet will return the details of the various drives available to your machine.

`Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem` will return, as you guessed it, file system drives! Pay particular attention to the `Root` property as this will show whether the drive in question is logical or remote.

You need to run this CmdLet when logged on the box, or alternatively you can use the `Invoke-Command` something like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ServerName" -Credential $(Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {
    Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
}
```

Comment: **@ALROC:** I can't UNC to the drive letter  
  
**JMONTEROHN:** I tried your suggestion. It didn't allow `Test-Path` to find the folder.  
  
**GVEE:** I remoted into the system and used `Get-PSDrive  -PSProvider FileSystem`.  The D drive is the one I'm trying to test. The D is listed with a ROOT of D:\ and PROVIDER of FileSystem.   
  
I have discovered the drive is in fact a thumb drive. I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in one of the comments that it is a thumbdrive. Thumbdrives are not administratively shared by windows and therefore that share does not exist.

If you create a folder on the thumbdrive, such as d:\test and share that as "test", then you can test-path to "\servername\test" and get a good result.